# Console.log is not working and I don't know why

Tags: console.log

I am not understanding conceptually why the console.log throws an error.

The error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at rearranger (:6:18)
    at :13:1

```
let vowels = [];
let consonants = [];
let s = "ellothere";
function rearranger(input) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= input.length; i++) {
        if (s[i].toLowerCase() === "a" || s[i].toLowerCase() === "e" || s[i].toLowerCase() === "i" || s[i].toLowerCase() === "o" || s[i].toLowerCase() === "u") {
           vowels = [...vowels, s[i]];
        } else {
           consonants = [...consonants, s[i]];
        }
    }
}
rearranger(s);
console.log(vowels, consonants);
```

Comment: Why dont you make a copy of your string like let copy = input.toLowerCase() instead of calling it 5 times per cycle? Where do you declare vowels? Why dont you call the console log inside the function after everything is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `for` loop to either:

```
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
```

or

```
for (let i = 0; i <= input.length -1 ; i++)
```

otherwise, you are iterating over the end of the string and getting the error.